# Power Amplifier Designing

Tags: amplifier

I am designing a power amplifier using [MRFE6VP61K25H](http://cache.nxp.com/files/rf_if/doc/data_sheet/MRFE6VP61K25H.pdf?pspll=1) at 27.12 MHz with 25watts power output. For that I've calculated the input and output impedance using S-parameter simulation in ADS by importing the model then I have done conjugate matching at both sides of the transistor. Can I get more gain after matching network designing, that is mention in Data Sheet?. The maximum gain mentioned in data sheet is 26dB but i am getting 32 dB gain. is it due to conjugate matching at the input and output end?

Answer (score 1):

The data sheet gives 24dB typical for Gps, with a range of 23dB to 26dB. Gps is defined as the gain in their 50 ohm matched fixture.

It's not clear on a quick read through (data sheet is TL;DR, you could be nice to question answerers by doing more homework on the data sheet to name key specs like Gps, and how it's defined) whether the matching they use for Gps is for max gain, max power output, min noise or simply 50 ohm presented to the ports (yes, they are all different).

The big difference is that you are running at 27MHz, but they spec their 24dB gain at 230MHz. There will be a huge difference in Gmax and S21 between those two frequencies, I would not be surprised to see 18dB difference, just on a frequency ratio basis (those port capacitances are large and dominating, even if gm was frequency independent over that range), but it could be less. There will also be a significant difference between the matching at those two frequencies.

Your 32dB is only 8dB more than their typical 230MHz gain, which is a long way short of the frequency ratio. Unfortunately, the data sheet doesn't plot any frequency dependent data. However, the Freescale site ought to have S parameters available in their design resources section, from which you can do a better estimate of the target 27MHz gain (edit - well waddayuknow, the S parameters are only given from 150MHz upwards /edit).